# RoR technology: is there any mobile framework on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can we make a mobile application with the help of [RoR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_on_Rails) technology?

Answer (score 2):

Ruby on Rails is a webframework designed to, well.. create websites. If you change the website template of RoR to fit the small screens of handhelds/mobile phones/smartphones you can of course use it to serve websites to those devices.

Best wishes,
Fabian

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is, "open source framework [Rhodes](http://rhomobile.com/2009/09/22/the-first-mobile-ruby/) contains the first implementation of Ruby for every major smartphone operating system: iPhone, Android, BlackBerry, Windows Mobile and Symbian." Also see [this](http://arstechnica.com/open-source/news/2009/03/rhomobile-unveils-ruby-based-cross-platform-mobile-framework.ars).